# Virtualbox wont start QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow)

Tags: virtualbox

Qt WARNING: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 460, resource id: 94371852, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0

Qt WARNING: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 461, resource id: 94371852, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0

The only solution i found was to add the environment variable QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=1 but this didn't work for me.

Comment: Linux Mint 18.3. No i haven't reinstalled, shouldn't be necessary should it? Ive seen these type of window errors in other programs before and was able to sort it out eventually. Im using another PC for the moment to run Windows so im not in a rush. I am gonna try it on a fresh install of Mint just to see what happens. Id like to figure it out either way though, I hate reinstalling. Always feels like defeat.

Comment: What version of Virtualbox? 5.2.24 or 6.0.2? I have had nothing but problems with 6.0.2 and windows guest on linux hosts. Downgrading to 5.2.24 resolved the issues (both versions support the 4.20 kernel)

Comment: 6.0.2, ill try 5.2.24.

Comment: Ya 5.2.24 is working fine ill stick with this for now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some ENV before launching VirtualBox. Create start script with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
exec virtualbox
```

Also check, that you have **xkeyboard-config** and **xauth** packages installed.

Comment: This helped on CentOS 6.10.

Comment: And on CentOS 7, this problem was driving me crazy! I cannot thank this guy enough

Comment: Works on Solaris 11.4 as well.  Thank you. (Change exec virtualbox to exec /opt/VirtualBox/VirtualBox)